# Bulk Action in wp_list_table

Tags: php, wordpress

I only want to do bulk action on delete function. I have research so many example on google but still cant make it. Will be so much appreciate if someone be able to help me out on this. Below are my codes. When Select and choose delete on drop down and click apply, nothing is happen.

```
public function get_bulk_actions(){
    $action = array(
        "delete" =>"Delete"
    );
    return $action; 
}

public function get_columns(){
    $columns = array(
        "cb"=>"<input type='checkbox'/>",
        "No"=>"No",
        "Name"=>"Name",
        "Email"=>"Email",
        "Unique_Code"=>"Unique Code",
        "Created_date"=>"Created Date"
    );
        return $columns;
 }

 public function column_cb($item){
    return sprintf('<input type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="%s"/>',$item['id'] );
 }

public function process_bulk_action() {

// If the delete bulk action is triggered
 $action = $this->current_action();
        if( 'delete'===$action ) {
        $delete_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['post'] );
        // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
            foreach ( $delete_ids as $did ) {
                global $wpdb;
                $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare( "DELETE FROM mncplugin WHERE id='".$did."'"));
            }

                    wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg() ) );
                    exit;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the method `process_bulk_action()` inside the method `prepare_items()`

Please find the gist which I created: https://gist.github.com/gvgvgvijayan/d46a52ca47309d1685ac91db3e9cf759#file-admin-table-tut-php-L272

Snippet:

```
public function prepare_items() {
    $columns               = $this->get_columns();
    $sortable              = $this->get_sortable_columns();
    $hidden                = array();
    $primary               = 'title';
    $this->_column_headers = array( $columns, $hidden, $sortable, $primary );
    $data                  = array();

    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $get_posts_obj = $this->get_posts_object();

    if ( $get_posts_obj->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $get_posts_obj->have_posts() ) {

            $get_posts_obj->the_post();

            $data[ get_the_ID() ] = array(
                'id'     => get_the_ID(),
                'title'  => get_the_title(),
                'type'   => ucwords( get_post_type_object( get_post_type() )->labels->singular_name ),
                'date'   => get_post_datetime(),
                'author' => get_the_author(),
            );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    $this->items = $data;

    $this->set_pagination_args(
        array(
            'total_items' => $get_posts_obj->found_posts,
            'per_page'    => $get_posts_obj->post_count,
            'total_pages' => $get_posts_obj->max_num_pages,
        )
    );
}
```

---

### Update 1:

Place all of your class method calls inside the `form` tag as below snippet.

```
function show_list_table() {
    $mnc_list_table = new MNCTableClass();
    echo '<h3>MNC List</h3>';
    echo "<form method='post' name='frm_search_post' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?page=alluserentries'>";
    $mnc_list_table->prepare_items();
    $mnc_list_table->display();
    $mnc_list_table->search_box("Search", "search_post_id");
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying me, i have insert the  ``` $this->process_bulk_action();``` into method ```prepare_items()```

Comment: but i still cannot get what i want, can you please point out the place where i need to make correction?

Comment: Add your full class for analysis

Comment: I have uploaded my code in [here](https://gist.github.com/Ivan97You/996faa490f16aaaa471b2de98c6544dc) , pls take a look

Comment: Check `process_bulk_action()` is called by either using xdebug or var_dump method

Comment: hi sir, which should i throw inside var_dumb? im not very ood at it. Hope you can guide me thru

Comment: Just call some plain text is enough for e.g. `public function process_bulk_action() { var_dump('bulk action called');`

Comment: thanks you sir, it look like [this](https://imgur.com/upMQm7V)

Comment: Welcome, I believe this is displayed after bulk action's apply button clicked. The next test is check is post's PK passed properly to the delete db call by printing the `$_POST['post']` and check the action name by printing `$this->current_action()`

Comment: no sir, i have make changes to [this](https://imgur.com/EcWvCEs).

Comment: i command the function and use your example to print out result. The 'Apply button' was never working at the beginning

Comment: No problem, I hope you will get the desired output by exploring the gist. Stuck anywhere `var_dump` if that also not resolved, add your query here.

Comment: The 'Apply' button is not functioning, i have place ver_dump into the function but when selected the check box and click apply button, there is no response at all. My code are all [here](https://gist.github.com/Ivan97You/996faa490f16aaaa471b2de98c6544dc) already. Please kindly take a look, thanks you mister for the patient to guide me thru

Comment: var_dump `$this->current_action();` and check it's equal to `delete` then check `$wpdp` delete query called

Comment: I have `var_dump ($this->current_action());`  and it show bool(false) at the top left corner of my screen. I have `print_r ($wpdb);` but cannot show anything, i think its because the function is not running...

Comment: if my code is complicated and kind of wasting time, is there anyway for me to re-write a code that has the function that trigger the bulk delete button?

Comment: Your's is more or less similar to what I shared in the gist, you got a clue `var_dump ($this->current_action());` is not returning `delete` please check why it's not showing `delete`

Comment: ok, sure, i will check. and once again thanks for your guide. Anything i will reply here, hopin you to help me again. thanks~

Comment: hi @gvgvgvijayan , after some searching, i have edited some of the code, i think its become more easy to see and work, but i still facing same problem, apply function is not working....hmm, really need some serious help.  pls help me take a [look](https://gist.github.com/Ivan97You/1c68f9e1946de6abf1eee7f36a021543) pls, thanks in advance